# "Ambiguous Name Detected"

Tags: vba, excel, ambiguity

I am currently having issues with having the second sub section work. I had an error:

> Ambigious name detected:Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick

I tried changing the second name but the code still didn't work. Both Subs work individually but putting them together only the top piece works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim HotArea As Range

Set HotArea = Range("C17,C21,C25,C29,C33,C42,C46,C50,C54,C58,C67,C71,C75,C83,C87,C91,C100,M17")
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("M21,M25,M29,M33,M42,M46,M55,M59,M69,M73,M82,M86,W17,W21,W25,W29,AG17,AG21,AG25,AG34"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AG38,AG42,AG51,AG55,AG59,AG68,AG72,AG81,AG85,AG89,AG98,AG102,AG106,AG110,AG114,AQ17"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AQ21,AQ30,AQ34,AQ43,AQ47,AQ51,AQ60,AQ64,BA17,BA21,BA25,BA29,BA33,BA37,BA46,BA50,BA54"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("BA58,BA62,BA71,BA75,BA79,BA89,BA93"))

If Not Intersect(Target, HotArea) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Item(1)
Case ""
    Target = "P1"
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Case "P1"
    Target = "P2"
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Case "P2"
    Target = "P3"
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 50
Case "P3"
    Target = "P4"
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 23
Case Else
    Target = ""
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Select
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim HotArea As Range

Set HotArea = Range("C19,C23,C27,C31,C35,C44,C48,C52,C56,C60,C69,C73,C77,C85,C89,C93,C102,M19")
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("M23,M27,M31,M35,M44,M48,M57,M61,M71,M75,M84,M88,W19,W23,W27,W31,AG19,AG23,AG27,AG36"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AG40,AG44,AG53,AG57,AG61,AG70,AG74,AG83,AG87,AG91,AG100,AG104,AG108,AG112,AG116,AQ19"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AQ23,AQ32,AQ36,AQ45,AQ49,AQ53,AQ62,AQ66,BA19,BA23,BA27,BA31,BA35,BA39,BA48,BA52,BA56"))
Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("BA60,BA64,BA73,BA77,BA81,BA91,BA95"))

If Not Intersect(Target, HotArea) Is Nothing Then

    'If the target cell is clear
    If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
    'Then change the background to the specified color
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

'But if the target cell is already the specified color
    ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then

    'Then change the background to the specified color
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

   'But if the target cell is already the specified color
    ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

    'Then change the background to the specified color
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    'But if the target cell is already the specified color
    ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

    'Then change the background to the specified color
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 5

    'But if the target cell is already the specified color
    ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 5 Then

    'Then change the background to the specified color
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = x1None
End If
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

How do I change the name so that both will work?

Comment: *All procedures in a code module must have a unique name.*  Give them different names? Otherwise, it's hard to say how to "fix" them unless you can say what you mean by "they don't work".  You have two procedures taht look very similar, while you could *combine* them, it's not clear that is your actual intent.

Comment: @DavidZemens In this case I disagree. It is very clear. They are both THE SAME event procedure of a worksheet.

Comment: It is not immediately/explicitly clear whether they *ought* to be combined, because the "second" procedure completely redefines the `HotArea` range, and implicitly because "but putting them together only the top piece works." which would seem to imply that something about the second piece "doesn't work" (whatever that means) when they are "combined". @ExcelHero

Comment: I'm not going to debug them. The question is why the error is happening. I've answered that and given a hint as to how to get both procedures to run in response to the event. OP needs to take it from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All procedures in a code module must have a unique name.

Here, I have taken the code from inside the 2nd instance of the procedure and appended it to the bottom of the first:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim HotArea As Range

    Set HotArea = Range("C17,C21,C25,C29,C33,C42,C46,C50,C54,C58,C67,C71,C75,C83,C87,C91,C100,M17")
    Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("M21,M25,M29,M33,M42,M46,M55,M59,M69,M73,M82,M86,W17,W21,W25,W29,AG17,AG21,AG25,AG34"))
    Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AG38,AG42,AG51,AG55,AG59,AG68,AG72,AG81,AG85,AG89,AG98,AG102,AG106,AG110,AG114,AQ17"))
    Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AQ21,AQ30,AQ34,AQ43,AQ47,AQ51,AQ60,AQ64,BA17,BA21,BA25,BA29,BA33,BA37,BA46,BA50,BA54"))
    Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("BA58,BA62,BA71,BA75,BA79,BA89,BA93"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, HotArea) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Item(1)
    Case ""
        Target = "P1"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Case "P1"
        Target = "P2"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Case "P2"
        Target = "P3"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 50
    Case "P3"
        Target = "P4"
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 23
    Case Else
        Target = ""
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End Select
    Cancel = True
    End If



    Set HotArea = Range("C19,C23,C27,C31,C35,C44,C48,C52,C56,C60,C69,C73,C77,C85,C89,C93,C102,M19")
    Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("M23,M27,M31,M35,M44,M48,M57,M61,M71,M75,M84,M88,W19,W23,W27,W31,AG19,AG23,AG27,AG36"))
    Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AG40,AG44,AG53,AG57,AG61,AG70,AG74,AG83,AG87,AG91,AG100,AG104,AG108,AG112,AG116,AQ19"))
    Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("AQ23,AQ32,AQ36,AQ45,AQ49,AQ53,AQ62,AQ66,BA19,BA23,BA27,BA31,BA35,BA39,BA48,BA52,BA56"))
    Set HotArea = Union(HotArea, Range("BA60,BA64,BA73,BA77,BA81,BA91,BA95"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, HotArea) Is Nothing Then

        'If the target cell is clear
        If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        'Then change the background to the specified color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    'But if the target cell is already the specified color
        ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then

        'Then change the background to the specified color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

       'But if the target cell is already the specified color
        ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

        'Then change the background to the specified color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        'But if the target cell is already the specified color
        ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

        'Then change the background to the specified color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 5

        'But if the target cell is already the specified color
        ElseIf Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 5 Then

        'Then change the background to the specified color
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = x1None
    End If
    Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That resolved my issue. I appreciate it. @ExcelHero